# Configure which browser to use when debugging with the new Visual Studio Angular and ASP.NET core (preview) template

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular

I've created a new project using the new Visual Studio "Angular and ASP.NET Core (Preview)" template as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-angular?source=recommendations&view=vs-2022.

When debugging I'd like the Angular app to run in a browser that I choose (I want to choose Chrome) but it runs in the OS's default browser (Edge).

Changing options in Visual Studio's Start menu only changes the browser the ASP.NET app runs in.

Answer (score 0):

Look in launch.json from .vscode folder. I have switched the order between edge and chrome. But I couldn't make it work for Firefox. I couldn't find any documentation on this issue.